# How to get current time of an html video in c# codebehind?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have added video control in ASP.NET page.

```xml
<video controls id="movie" width="610" height="344" runat="server" preload="">
</video>
```

Javascript version is below:

```js
var v = $("#<%=movie.ClientID%>");
var video = v.get()[0];
```

I can get current time with below line in Javascript.

```js
video.currentTime
```

How can I get it from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get it using Javascript and submit it to the codebehind:

```js
$.get("passVideoTime.aspx?time=" + video.currentTime);
```

Or using a postback:

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField Id="VideoTime"  runat="server"/>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Enabled="true" Interval="1000" ID="Timer" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```js
<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#<%= VideoTime.ClientId %>').val(video.currentTime);
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Edit: the postback example does not really work, because a postback does not cause a form.submit. It is not so easy to update something just before the updatepanel is updated.